# Export of whole database from one hbase to another

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Recently I started working on HBase. Now I need to get the application data on one HBase system to another. How can I export dump of whole HBase from one system to another.

Comment: Is your system full distributed? What's the configuration and HBase version?

Comment: Yes the system is full distributed

Answer (score 0):

You can use hbase Export/Import command for transferring data from one hbase cluster to another.

Please refer below link.

http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops_mgt.html

Comment: Shashi: This actually copies individual table rather I want to replicate whole namespace.

Comment: What is your hbase version?

Comment: Here is Jira ticket for Namespace https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-8015  looks like there is no special command for namespace migration.